# Querying (Wordpress) MySQL Database using asp.net OR sending data from wordpress to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I'm working on a Press Release website that currently has an existing distribution platform built on ASP.NET - the site that I have built is utilizes Wordpress Multi-site and BuddyPress, and I need to share information between Wordpress & the existing ASP.NET CMS.

The information that needs to be shared between both platforms is 1) Press release information (which is a custom post type in Wordpress) and 2) The login information.

Is there a way to have ASP.NET get the information from the Wordpress MYSQL database?  Or is the best way to write a plugin for wordpress that will send information to the ASP.NET each time a new press release is written, and each time a new user account is created.

I can go either way - having ASP.NET grab the info, or Wordpress send the info out.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the WordPress XML-RPC API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to see e.g. how to create, read, update & delete posts.